# Duplicating rows based on a column value in each row

Tags: sql-server

I've this table with the following data

```
Job    Quantity Status Repeat
1      100      OK     2
2      400      HOLD   0
3      200      HOLD   1
4      450      OK     3
```

Based on the value in the Repeat column for each row, the row should be repeated again. For example for the Job 1, Repeat value is 2 so the Job 1 should repeat two more times.

The resultant table should be as below

```
Job    Quantity Status Repeat
1      100      OK     2
1      100      OK     2
1      100      OK     2
2      400      HOLD   0
3      200      HOLD   1
3      200      HOLD   1
4      450      OK     3
4      450      OK     3
4      450      OK     3
4      450      OK     3
```

Can someone please help me out with this query?

I'm using sql server

Comment: Is there any reasonable limit on possible values in `Repeat`?

Comment: I don't think you can downvote your own question, even if you wanted to in a fit of self-effacement. I was asking the person who downvoted your question, it seems pretty valid and interesting to me.

Comment: Oh ok. Sorry I misunderstood. Thanks for your time & consideration

Answer (score 13, accepted):

This will support over 7,400 repeats for any individual job (on my system). If you need more, you can use a different system table or a cross join.

```
DECLARE @d TABLE (Job INT, Quantity INT, Status VARCHAR(12), Repeat INT);

INSERT @d SELECT 1, 100, 'OK'  ,2
UNION ALL SELECT 2, 400, 'HOLD',0
UNION ALL SELECT 3, 200, 'HOLD',1
UNION ALL SELECT 4, 450, 'OK'  ,3;

WITH x AS 
(
  SELECT TOP (SELECT MAX(Repeat)+1 FROM @d) rn = ROW_NUMBER() 
  OVER (ORDER BY [object_id]) 
  FROM sys.all_columns 
  ORDER BY [object_id]
)
SELECT * FROM x
CROSS JOIN @d AS d
WHERE x.rn <= d.Repeat + 1
ORDER BY Job;
```

Comment: It worked. I'm a newbie so can u please once explain this query. I didn't understand from WITH

Comment: `WITH` represents a [common table expression](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175972.aspx). Inside, we just pull a set of numbers from a system table that is guaranteed to have plenty of rows (I assume 7,400 should be enough in your case). We use `TOP` to limit that number to one greater than the largest `Repeat` value in your table. Then using those numbers we perform a cross join so that we have a row from the CTE for each number <= `Repeat` per job. And we add 1 on that side as well (this ensures that you also include the rows where `Repeat = 0`).

Answer (score 5):

```
DECLARE @repeats TABLE
        (
        rn INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY
        );

WITH    q (rn, m) AS
        (
        SELECT  1, MAX(repeat) + 1
        FROM    jobs
        UNION ALL
        SELECT  rn + 1, m
        FROM    q
        WHERE   rn < m
        )
INSERT
INTO    @repeats
SELECT  rn
FROM    q

SELECT  j.*
FROM    jobs j
CROSS APPLY
        (
        SELECT  TOP (j.repeat + 1)
                NULL
        FROM    @repeats
        ) q (repeat)
```

If you have a table which guaranteedly has more records than the maximum possible value of `repeat`, you may get rid of `@repeats` and use that table instead.

Answer (score 1):

I prefer the below approach, as it is not reliant on external data for the query to be successful and is fairly straight forward. I've used Aaron Bertrand's code to initialize the data table but my approach on how to repeat data - this approach does not require a specific table to contain more rows than the required recursions / not dependent on external data.

```
DECLARE @d TABLE (Job INT, Quantity INT, Status VARCHAR(12), Repeat INT);

INSERT @d SELECT 1, 100, 'OK'  , 2
UNION ALL SELECT 2, 400, 'HOLD', 0
UNION ALL SELECT 3, 200, 'HOLD', 1
UNION ALL SELECT 4, 450, 'OK'  , 3;

DECLARE @maxRecursion INT;
SET @maxRecursion = (SELECT MAX(Repeat) 
                       FROM @d);    

WITH Iterator AS 
(
    SELECT 1 AS Iterations
    UNION ALL
    SELECT Iterations + 1 FROM Iterator WHERE Iterations < @maxRecursion
)

SELECT A.*
  FROM @d AS A
 RIGHT JOIN Iterator ON Iterator.Iterations <= (A.Repeat + 1)
 ORDER BY Job ASC
OPTION (MAXRECURSION 0)
```

Cheers!

Answer (score -1):

You may write stored procedure which will do this query (as cursor) and then you may fill new temporary table as you want

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[GetRepeatJobs]()
RETURNS 
@JobsRepeatTable TABLE (JobId int, JobName nchar(10))
AS
BEGIN
DECLARE @i int
DECLARE @j int
DECLARE @JobId int
DECLARE @JobName nchar(10)

DECLARE JobsCursor CURSOR FOR (select JobId, JobName, JobRepeat from jobs)
OPEN JobsCursor
FETCH NEXT FROM JobsCursor INTO @JobId, @JobName, @i

WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
BEGIN
    SELECT @j = 0
    WHILE @j < @i
    BEGIN
        INSERT INTO @JobsRepeatTable VALUES (@JobId, @JobName)
        SELECT @j = @j+1    
    END
    FETCH NEXT FROM JobsCursor INTO @JobId, @JobName, @i
END 
RETURN 
END
```

Works perfect for me.

Comment: this is not good for performance...using WHILE (without cursor) maybe increase performance...but cte table is very fasty