# Insert a row, based on a fields value

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, t-sql

My data looks like this

```
Supplier  Qty  
--------  ---  
ABC       3
BCD       1  
CDE       2  
DEF       1
```

I expect the result to be:

```
Supplier  Qty  
--------  ---  
ABC       3   }---> Add additional row based on the number of qty
ABC       3   }
ABC       3   }
BCD       1  
CDE       2   }---> Add additional row here too
CDE       2   }
DEF       1
```

Looking for an sql SELECT statement that performs the expected result.
I am using Sql Server 2008

Comment: is there a maximum in QTY that is allowed or could there be any number?

Comment: +1 for the interesting question

Comment: Are you inserting into the same table, or into a new table?

Comment: So you're attempting to make the number of rows per `Supplier` equal to the `Qty`

Comment: possible duplicate of [Duplicating rows based on a column value in each row](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10902419/duplicating-rows-based-on-a-column-value-in-each-row)

Comment: Yes, I need to get the number of rows equal to the ' qty '

Comment: Trying to select the records from a table and should add the rows as expected as per sample. The maximum number in 'qty' is expected to be 10

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
DECLARE @d TABLE (Supplier VARCHAR(32), Quantity INT);

INSERT @d SELECT 'ABC',3
UNION ALL SELECT 'BCD',1  
UNION ALL SELECT 'CDE',2  
UNION ALL SELECT 'DEF',1;

WITH x AS 
(
  SELECT TOP (10) rn = ROW_NUMBER() --since OP stated max = 10
  OVER (ORDER BY [object_id]) 
  FROM sys.all_columns 
  ORDER BY [object_id]
)
SELECT d.Supplier, d.Quantity
FROM x
CROSS JOIN @d AS d
WHERE x.rn <= d.Quantity
ORDER BY d.Supplier;
```

Comment: (...double the points! Nice work Aaron) It is a great query - is there not a prettier way of filling you CTE?

Comment: @whytheq like what? Note that the OP *just* stated that the max is 10.

Comment: I asked the question! All it returns is a list of numbers 1,2,3..Max; I just thought there might be a prettier way of getting it.

Comment: So are you Nishal or whytheq? Anyway SQL Server doesn't have a built-in table of numbers. You could manually write out `SELECT rn = 1 UNION SELECT rn = 2` etc. but I find the above "prettier" even if it means it accesses a catalog view.

Comment: Perfect! Many thanks for your answer. (Up vote and accepted your answer)

Comment: I believe you but I've added the question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11020311/returning-a-list-of-numbers-upto-a-set-value-using-sql

Answer (score 4):

Assuming you are inserting back into the same table, using a CTE to figure out what rows to insert works cleanly.  This will **not** work if the Quantity is greater than the max recursion level (which I believe is 100 by default) and so may not be an appropriate solution.

```
;WITH SupplyToInsert (Supplier, Qty) AS (
    SELECT Supplier, Qty - 1
    FROM Supply
    WHERE Qty > 1

    UNION ALL

    SELECT S.Supplier, I.Qty - 1
    FROM Supply S
        INNER JOIN SupplyToInsert I ON I.Supplier = S.Supplier
    WHERE I.Qty > 1
)
INSERT INTO Supply (Supplier, Qty)
SELECT I.Supplier, S.Qty
FROM SupplyToInsert I
    INNER JOIN Supply S ON S.Supplier = I.Supplier
```

If you arent inserting back into the same table, change each `Qty > 1` to `Qty > 0` in the CTE, to get one extra row for each supplier.

Working [SqlFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/9e561/10)

Comment: +1 Creative.  For my own education: is ;with cte a purely SQL solution or does it require T-SQL functions to work?  I guess I'm asking is ;with cte a strictly SQL answer.

Answer (score 2):

By no means the prettiest of things; and assumes QTY will never exceed 10.
There are better ways to do this...  but would involve PL\SQL or T-SQL can't think of a straight SQL answer.

```
Insert into yourTablename
(
(Select supplier, Qty From YourTableName where Qty-1 > 0) 
UNION
(Select supplier, Qty From YourTableName where Qty-2 > 0) 
UNION
(Select supplier, Qty From YourTableName where Qty-3 > 0) 
UNION
(Select supplier, Qty From YourTableName where Qty-4 > 0) 
UNION
(Select supplier, Qty From YourTableName where Qty-5 > 0) 
UNION
(Select supplier, Qty From YourTableName where Qty-6 > 0) 
UNION
(Select supplier, Qty From YourTableName where Qty-7 > 0) 
UNION
(Select supplier, Qty From YourTableName where Qty-8 > 0) 
UNION
(Select supplier, Qty From YourTableName where Qty-9 > 0) 
UNION
(Select supplier, Qty From YourTableName where Qty-10 > 0) 
)
```

Furthermore this is a one shot deal; if this doesn't do it right the first time; you'd have to clean up the data and then try again.  (again not my favorite answer but limiting to JUST SQL...)

Comment: can you just change the above to a loop with the condition involving the maximum value of Qty

Comment: Yes, but a LOOP involves T-SQL and is not strictly a SQL answer.