# Returning a list of numbers up to a set value

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I've seen the following used to return a list of numbers

```
SELECT TOP (SELECT MAX(Quantity) FROM @d) 
       rn = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY object_id)    
FROM   sys.all_columns 
ORDER BY object_id
```

if the max quantity is 5 then I assume the above returns:

```
rn
1
2
3
4
5
```

Is there a more elegant, or even canonical, approach within T-SQL to return this list of numbers?

Comment: I'm going to rely on the age-old IT answer to this sort of question ... "It Depends."

Comment: I'm using T-sql on sql-server 2008 R2 ...I'll add this to the question

Comment: In this case the version of SQL Server doesn't really change much (except in 2000 you wouldn't be able to use ROW_NUMBER() or sys.all_anything).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can do:

```
SELECT        rn = 1 
  UNION ALL SELECT 2 
  UNION ALL SELECT 3 
  UNION ALL SELECT 4 
  UNION ALL SELECT 5;
```

This is tolerable when the number is 5, but not 50 or 5000. When you need more you can do things like use a CTE to build up a set of numbers to then cross join to explode the set (you can see a couple of examples [here, under Inline 1 / Inline 2](https://sqlblog.org/2010/07/07/splitting-a-list-of-integers-another-roundup)).

Or you can build a table of Numbers, let's say you may need 5 or you may need a million:

```
SET NOCOUNT ON;
 
DECLARE @UpperLimit INT = 1000000;
 
WITH n AS
(
    SELECT
        x = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY s1.[object_id])
    FROM       sys.all_objects AS s1
    CROSS JOIN sys.all_objects AS s2
    CROSS JOIN sys.all_objects AS s3
)
SELECT Number = x
  INTO dbo.Numbers
  FROM n
  WHERE x BETWEEN 1 AND @UpperLimit;
 
GO
CREATE UNIQUE CLUSTERED INDEX n ON dbo.Numbers(Number);
GO
```

Then when you want some numbers you just say:

```
SELECT TOP (5) rn = Number 
  FROM dbo.Numbers 
  ORDER BY Number;
```

Obviously using sys.all_columns or any built-in object with sufficient rows avoids the up-front step of creating a Numbers table (which many people object to, for some reason, anyway).

Now, it would be really nice if there *were* a more elegant way to do this, wouldn't it? You won't see it in any current version but there's a chance we'll see it in a future version. Please go vote (and more importantly, comment on your use case) here:

http://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/details/258733/add-a-built-in-table-of-numbers

Comment: (+1 very "pretty"!) I like the extra cartesian products to multiply things up and guarantee enough records

Comment: I like the SQLCLR option supplied in the "workarounds" section of that Connect link. Sounds like about as good a solution as one could want, if the SQLCLR thing isn't a deal-breaker. I agree that it would be nice to have some of this in the base product, though.

Answer (score 4):

Definitely not the most elegant, but probably the fastest way for larger sequences:

```
WITH
 E1(N) AS (SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL
           SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL
           SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL
           SELECT 1),                 --10E1  or 10 rows
 E2(N) AS (SELECT 1 FROM E1 a, E1 b), --10E2  or 100 rows
 E4(N) AS (SELECT 1 FROM E2 a, E2 b), --10E3  or 10000 rows
 E8(N) AS (SELECT 1 FROM E4 a, E4 b)  --10E4  or 100000000 rows
SELECT TOP (@DesiredRowCount) N = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)) FROM E8
;
```

No temp tables, no table reads, and you can define your maximum yourself.

You can copy-paste the ready-to-use function from [here](https://mikeshilkov.wordpress.com/2014/06/03/sql-produce-resultset-with-n-rows/)

Answer (score 3):

I've used something like this in the past -- though it only works up to 100 or so:

```
WITH Numbers(number) AS (
SELECT 1 number
UNION ALL
SELECT number+1 FROM Numbers WHERE number < 10)
SELECT * FROM Numbers
```

Comment: You need to change the `MAXRECURSION` option.

Answer (score 3):

First create a table of numbers 0 - 9

```
create table dbo.Digits (digit tinyint not null Primary Key) 
insert into dbo.Digits values (0), (1), (2), (3), (4), (5), (6), (7), (8), (9)
```

Then you can produce the following cross join to count from 1 to 100:

```
select
D2.digit * 10 + 
D1.digit + 1 as n
from dbo.Digits D1,
dbo.Digits D2
order by n
```

To count from 1 to 1000, you simply need to add an additional cross join:

```
select
D3.digit * 100 +
D2.digit * 10 + 
D1.digit + 1 as n
from dbo.Digits D1,
dbo.Digits D2,
dbo.Digits D3
order by n
```

To count from 1 to x (where x <= 1000)::

```
select top x
D3.digit * 100 +
D2.digit * 10 + 
D1.digit + 1 as n
from dbo.Digits D1,
dbo.Digits D2,
dbo.Digits D3
order by n
```

Answer (score 1):

Modify the Top value as required:

```
SELECT TOP 30 ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY [object_id]) 
FROM sys.all_objects
```

e.g. A dropdown list showing a range of NULL, 1 - 30 for a list of years of education.

```
<tr>
<td>Education</td>
<td>
<asp:DropDownList ID="EducationDropDownList" runat="server" DataSourceID="sd6"
 DataValueField="Education" DataTextField="Education" 
 SelectedValue='<%# Bind("Education") %>' CssClass="metro" />
<asp:SqlDataSource ID="sd6" runat="server" 
 ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:cnYours %>" 
 SelectCommand="SELECT NULL AS Education UNION ALL SELECT TOP 30 ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY [object_id]) FROM sys.all_objects" 
 SelectCommandType="Text" />
</td>
</tr>
```

Comment: not ideal: currently  doesn't work for anything greater than 4476 on my db: better with a crossjoin

Answer (score 1):

If you only wanted your output to contain a running number as an additional column, the following would work as well:

```
select row_number() over (order by (Select 1)) AS RowNum, * from Table_1 where Column_3 = 372 and Column_6 = 2017;
```

Answer (score 0):

if you are on sql 2022 or azure where `string_split` supports `ordinal`, you can do this for a million numbers for example:

```sql
SELECT 
ss.ordinal 
FROM
STRING_SPLIT(REPLICATE(CAST('.' AS VARCHAR(max)),999999),'.',1) ss
```