# Repeat Rows in table without numbers table

Tags: sql, sql-server

How can we repeat the existing rows up to 10,000 times using a stored procedure? Do we have to use while loop?
My table `Student` has 3 columns like `Name, ID, Marks.` currently it has 10 records in it.

```
Sample Data:
ID  Name  Marks
1   John   88
2   Dave   98

Expected Data:
ID  Name  Marks
    1   John   88
    2   Dave   98
    1   John   88
    2   Dave   98
    1   John   88
    2   Dave   98
    1   John   88
    2   Dave   98
```

Expected data row count should be 10,000.

Comment: Please explain what you mean by *repeat existing rows*.  What are you expecting to happen?  Please some some sample data and desired results.

Comment: You can use a `while` loop, a numbers table, or a recursive CTE.

Comment: use 1000 union all's if you don't want to use a numbers table.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10902419/duplicating-rows-based-on-a-column-value-in-each-row

Comment: Why the requirement to not use a numbers table? That is the right tool for this. Using a loop for this is entirely the wrong way to go about it.

Comment: ok. How to use the numbers table in this scenario?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you can't/don't want to use a numbers table, you can use `GO` in SSMS to specify how many times you want the statement executed:

```
Insert  Student
        (Id, Name, Marks)
Select  Distinct Id, Name, Marks
From    Student
Go 5000
```

The above statement would execute `5,000` times, resulting in `10,000` records inserted.

Comment: What if I have 10 existing rows? How do i add them to values? Can i use a select statement to select the existing rows?

Comment: @ananthreddy Updated.  This would duplicate each student the number of specified times.

Comment: Actually that is the requirement for me

Answer (score 1):

> **Edit - Missed the 10,000 row count... corrected**

This is an ad-hoc numbers/tally table... does that count?

```
Declare @YourTable table (ID int,Name varchar(50),Marks int)
Insert Into @YourTable values
(1,'John',88),
(2,'Dave',98)

;with cte0(N) As (Select 1 From (Values(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1)) N(N)),
      cteN(N) As (Select Top (10000/(select count(*) from @YourTable)) Row_Number() over (Order By (Select NULL)) From cte0 N1, cte0 N2, cte0 N3, cte0 N4) -- 10,000
Select A.*
 From  @YourTable A
 Cross Join cteN B
```

**Or another option**

```
Select A.*
 From  @YourTable A
 Cross Join (Select Top (10000/(select count(*) from @YourTable)) N=Row_Number() Over (Order By (Select Null)) From master..spt_values N1,master..spt_values N2) B
```