# How to create duplicate rows based on a column values

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g, recursive-query

I need to duplicate resulted rows based on a column value.
I already read a few posts like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10902419/duplicating-rows-based-on-a-column-value-in-each-row), but I wasn't able to translate this so it would work on my oracle database.

I got two tables. The first stores a text value and the second defines the number of repetition.

```
CREATE TABLE TestTable1 (
  id NUMBER(9), 
  Text VARCHAR2(10)  
);

CREATE TABLE TestTable2 (
  id NUMBER(9), 
  Repeat NUMBER(9)  
);

insert into TestTable1(
select 101, 'ABC' from dual union all
select 202, 'DEF' from dual union all
select 303, 'GHI' from dual);

insert into TestTable2(
select 101, 2 from dual union all
select 202, 13 from dual union all
select 303, 24 from dual);
```

So when I join the tables like this

```
select T1.ID, T1.TEXT, T2.REPEAT 
  from TestTable1 t1
  join TestTable2 t2
    on T1.ID = T2.ID;
```

I get this result

```
ID      TEXT    REPEAT
---------------------------
101     ABC     2
202     DEF     13
303     GHI     24
```

But I need 2 rows with the text 'ABC', 13 rows with 'DEF' and 24 rows with 'GHI'.
How can i make this work?
Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [Hierarchical Query](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/queries003.htm)

```
select T1.ID, T1.TEXT
  from TestTable1 t1
  join TestTable2 t2
    on T1.ID = T2.ID
 connect by level <= T2.repeat  
    and prior T1.ID = T1.ID
    and prior sys_guid() is not null;
```

<kbd>[Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=f05ad4f87c49833fe74b1e136df94320)</kbd>